# Microsoft emotion api video version with javascript

Tags: javascript, face-detection, face-recognition

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Emotion API.

I can use the image version without any issues but when I try to use the video version I get an empty response.

It seems that I can successfully connect with the API because when I give it a wrong file type it returns the proper error code.

Here is my code. Would appreciate any help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //apiKey: Replace this with your own Project Oxford Emotion API key, please do not use my key. I inlcude it here so you can get up and running quickly but you can get your own key for free at https://www.projectoxford.ai/emotion 
    var apiKey = "mykey";

    //apiUrl: The base URL for the API. Find out what this is for other APIs via the API documentation
    var apiUrl = "https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognizeinvideo";

    $('#btn').click(function () {
        CallAPI("https://media.kairos.com/emodemo/videos/demo1.mp4", apiUrl, apiKey);
    });

    function CallAPI(fileUrl, apiUrl, apiKey)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: apiUrl,
            beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey);
            },
            type: "POST",
            data: '{"url": "' +fileUrl +'"}'
        })
            .done(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                //ProcessResult(response);
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                $("#response").text(error.getAllResponseHeaders());
            });
    }

    function ProcessResult(response)
    {
        var data = JSON.stringify(response);
        $("#response").text(data);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Add the error code or description

Comment: hello
there is no error code if I give the api the right filetype.
My main problem is that why it always detect nothing and give me a empty response.